# Error while implementing django models . How to debug?

Tags: django-models

```
Error: One or more models did not validate:
maps.parking: 'layer_id' has a relation with model sdr_layer.Sdr_layer, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
```

This is the error that I have .

```
My maps/models.py looks like this 
# This is an auto-generated Django model module created by ogrinspect.
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Parking(models.Model):
    layer_id= models.ForeignKey(sdr_layer.Sdr_layer)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    descriptio = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    geom = models.PointField(srid=4326)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

# Auto-generated `LayerMapping` dictionary for Parking model
parking_mapping = {
    'name' : 'Name',
    'descriptio' : 'Descriptio',
    'geom' : 'POINT25D',
}
```

Where sdr_layer/models.py looks like this

```
from django.db import models

    class Sdr_Layer(models.Model):
       layer_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
       layer_attribute_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

I basically want the Sdr_layer.id to act as the foreign key for the app maps .

Comment: Did you forget to include the definition of `sdr_layer.Sdr_layer`?

Comment: You mean importing the app.model into maps/models.py ?

Comment: I am pretty much clueless here .

Comment: `Parking.layer_id` relates to `sdr_layer.Sdr_layer`. You have shown the definition of `sdr_layer.models.Sdr_Layer`. Are you saying that those are supposed to be the same somehow?

Comment: So what is the way out ?

Comment: Are you saying that you need another hint?

Comment: I did the necessary changes . converted Sdr_layer to models.Sdr_Layer . Still the same error persists .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure sdr_layer is listed your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

Answer (score 0):

I think you intended `models.ForeignKey(sdr_layer.Sdr_Layer)`.